# Remove page numbers for one section in Word 2011?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-word-2011, page-numbers

I am running Microsoft Word 2011 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, and am editing a .docx Word document created with it.

I would like my title page to be without page numbers, so I added a "Section Break (Next Page)" at the end of the title page to start the main text where I would like to have page numbers.

I was able to insert page numbers to the main text from page one, but it also added a page number ("1") to the title page! Is there a way to remove that page number or limit page numbering to a specific section in my document? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out your link to previous settings in the headers or footers where the page numbers reside.

You can make sure that the page headers and footers in the different sections are not linked to each other.

EDIT: I realize the Mac version of word is a bit funny in the placement of things. Here is a [forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/header-footer-issues-with-word-2011-for-mac/75b54c8f-b1db-41e7-b40e-107a4e89d13f) where they explain how to find the options you need to un-link headers and footers

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what are links and where do I check them? Thanks!

Comment: in the headers footers/ribbon there should be spot called navigation. somewhere in there you should see the 'link to previous' option. Double click a header or footer to get to the ribbon. http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/136693-unlink-header-or-footer-in-ms-word-2011/

Comment: Glad to hear. Your welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can breaks all the pages you want to remove numbering to single pages and then you have many single pages numbered as 1 . now you can choose option "Different First Page" for all of your single page sections, that's it.